# How does SQL compiler knows which attribute is set to primary key?

Tags: mysql, sql

How does the SQL compiler knows which attribute is set to primary key and how does it prevent from adding duplicates in the primary key?

Comment: the db engine use the table schema and the index  constraints

Comment: Please refer [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to know this?

Comment: It knows which column is the primary key because you tell it when you create the table. As to how it prevents duplicates, that's internal code inside the database engine but presumably it checks all the existing records before proceeding with the insert. It may have an efficient way of doing it, of course

Answer (score 1):

The `PRIMARY KEY` is defined as part of the definition of a table.  It is one of several types of constraints that can be defined on a table.

Normally, the definition is part of the table creation statement:

```
create table t (
    t_id int auto_increment primary key,
    ------------------------^
    . . .
);
```

Or:

```
create table t (
    t_id int auto_increment,
    . . . ,
    constraint pk_t primary key (t_id)
--------------------^
    . . .
);
```

It can also be defined after the fact using `alter table`.

The table definition and associated constraints (and triggers) form the *metadata* for the table.  The primary key constraint has the following three conditions:

1. The columns comprising the key are not `NULL`.
2. The values of the combination of keys are not duplicated.
3. There is only one on the table.

You can achieve the first with a `NOT NULL` constraint; and the second with a `UNIQUE` constraint.  The third is specific to `PRIMARY KEY` constraints.